# How to use javascript:void(0) in menu of yii

Tags: yii

How to use `javascript:void(0)` in menu of `yii`

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array( 'items'=>array( array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('site/funtionname')),), )); ?>
```

i have tried using like this:-

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array( 'items'=>array( array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('javascript:void(0);')),), )); ?>
```

but its not working...

Answer (score 2):

only `'url'=> 'javascript:void(0);'` without using array